# How can i delete the backups of a specific database with specific time? I also don't want to give the path of the files. Can anyone guide me?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete the backups of a specific database with specific time. I also don't want to give the location of the backup folder. The query should take the backup folder path and delete the backups with given time of the specific database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @BACKUP TABLE (database_name VARCHAR(500),backup_start_date VARCHAR(500),physical_device_name VARCHAR(500))

DECLARE @DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(MAX),@DATE DATETIME,@BACK VARCHAR(8000)
SET @DATABASE_NAME='database name'
SET @DATE='2016-10-28 09:55:14.000'

INSERT INTO @BACKUP 
SELECT 
backupset.database_name, 
backupset.backup_start_date, 
backupmediafamily.physical_device_name
FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset 
ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id 
WHERE backupset.database_name=@DATABASE_NAME AND backupset.backup_start_date=@DATE

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @BACKUP)
BEGIN
    DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 'DEL '+PHYSICAL_DEVICE_NAME FROM @BACKUP
    OPEN C
    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @BACK
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
    EXEC XP_CMDSHELL @BACK
    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @BACK
    END
    CLOSE C
    DEALLOCATE C

END

ELSE
PRINT 'THE BACKUP FOR '+@DATABASE_NAME+' AT '+cast(@DATE as varchar(200))+' DOES NOT EXIST'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should back up database to logical backup device (it's similar to synonym for file path).

```
--Define a backup device and physical name.   
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_addumpdevice 'disk', 'mybackupdisk', 'c:\backup\backup1.bak' ;  
GO  
--Delete the backup device and the physical name.  
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_dropdevice ' mybackupdisk ', 'delfile' ;  
GO
```

read more about backup devices: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188711.aspx